# Unable to find LoginModule class: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule

Tags: java, websphere, spnego

Hi I am trying to start Websphere using Spnego Authentication. When the login should occur i am getting this exception

> javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule
>   class: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule in
>   SpnegoHttpFilter init method.

Any ideas why it is unable to find this class?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that IBM J9 JVM doesn't have `com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule`. It has `com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule`. And it can be used.

Comment: Note that the classes have different properties, and therefore you may need to change your config in other ways than just the name of a class.